# Using query export SQL Server 2008 table to Excel Sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, export

How to export sql server table data to excel sheet.

```
 insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Book1.xlsx;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select TOP 5 CustomerID from Customers
```

I used the above query but it shows following error

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' cannot be used for distributed queries
>   because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment
>   mode.

Comment: The solution is in http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/

Comment: I Tried that too. Even though it shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO     
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
 insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Book1.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') select TOP 5 CustomerID from Customers
```

Its working fine